# inserting values to one table and the same time inserting distict values to second table

Tags: sql, asp-classic

there are two tables.First one is Trans_Details and, the second one is Trans_Details_temp.When we insert the values to database through our asp website form, we have to access all records to first table.. and the same time, we have to access only distict values to second table.When a customer comes into our bank, he / she deposits/withdraw amount from bank.and the details should added into both the tables..and, the same customer comes next month for his/her second transaction, a second row is created in first table.
but, in the second table, the earlier row get updated only.no duplication should takes place in second table.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you have some form of specification. What you've forgotten to do though is *ask a question*. What problem(s) are you having?

Comment: You need to show us what you've done so far, also.